# Replace/refresh 7 segment display of vintage 80's clock radio

Tags: led, identification, repair, 7segmentdisplay, replacement

Past two weeks working on this clock radio because I love the looks of it and it is also pretty rare (it must be restored in original condition or better). Fixed almost every non-working feature such as (touch-) knobs, backlight (replaced bulbs with warm-white LED's - awesome result), potentiometers, speaker, ground noise, dirt and dust, casing etc. Arrived in bad shape however after all the effort it turns out to be very promising.

Still one problem left to be perfect, most important part of a clock, the numeric 7 segment display. Very dim, checked the voltages and such, it is just old, aged, the reason why it is dim because it needs to be replaced.

However, unable to find a replacement and searching for another route. Display is a red LED `Toshiba TLR4202` (noticed in the service manual of device). Don't know if it is possible to take the display apart and replace the LEDs with some new smd LEDs. Searched on this topic however cannot find anything/anyone done this before. To be sure don't screw up the display before trying because current one is only one I have. Cannot find either a display with same characteristics (same layout) and same size.

Another problem, each LED must fit the old school environment requirements, a LED can only consume 5mA (noticed in the limited datasheet of the display), the MK50366N (no datasheet found) display driver is a MOS IC (needs careful threatment experimenting with this).

Any suggestions what to do, to find a solution to this?

---

**Model**

[image: Model]

---

**Service manual (TLR4202)**
[image: Service manual display notice]

---

**Display layout (TLR4202)**

[image: display layout]
[image: display specs]

---

**Display Datasheet**

This page is the only page available:

[image: display datasheet]

Comment: If I read correctly, all you want to do is to replace the 7-segment displays and the LED colons. You do NOT want to replace (or damage) the clock chip: MK50366N. We don't have any information on the bezel (polarized?) But what have you excluded as unsuitable? I imagine that with some added effort, you should be able to find suitable 7-segment individual displays and can source individual LEDs for the colon dots. You may have to construct something to properly fix them with relationship to each other so that the display height and width is what you want. Is there a reason that can't be?

Comment: @jonk Hi, thanks for the comment. The window on the case is transparent. The LED display has a dark red window. Because the window on the case is transparent, everything you do behind this window is clearly visible. Maybe I have to include a picture of it, so I will add this after this comment. Just a moment please ;-)

Comment: Preserve that dark red window. At their simplest, they hinder reflections. But they were often also polarized so that reflections were completely killed and the contrast was maintained as high as possible. Do not damage it. Having it will likely allow you to use modern devices, appropriately mounted and positioned. Have you looked for high efficiency red 7 seg displays?

Comment: Just posted a picture, added it to the question. Just read your comment, just a moment.

Comment: Yes, I have searched everywhere and the modern displays doesn't have the exact layout or size. I was thinking of making a custom perf board version with smd LEDs and use the white plastic segment part to complete the looks. However I don't know if it is possible to take it apart without any damage, I haven't seen somebody did this before. And when I do this, I need to add some extra resistors to limit the current, The modern displays have a very different pin layout or multiplexed so I think this very difficult to do to fit into this old school design. What do you think about  this?

Comment: Hdsp-h103 is slightly smaller. But the right current. But depending on how picky you intend, you may be constructing these from individual LEDs and diffuser plastics. HP had an optoelectronics book that would be worth owning, if you don't already have a copy. (I bought all I could find of them some years back-- they are thorough beyond belief and cover everything from optical design to electronics. Beautiful, hardbound volumes.)

Comment: You are right I don't want to replace or damage the clock chip because it is not only the display driver.

Comment: Okay, take a look at it, just a moment.

Comment: [HDSP-H103](https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/broadcom-limited/HDSP-H103/516-1229-5-ND/637493).

Comment: [HP optoelectronics](https://www.amazon.com/dp/B00JCUNGRS/ref=cm_sw_r_cp_apa_i_1YZDDb4KE14D4)

Comment: First one I found: On Farnell it is the same model number however with different specs - https://nl.farnell.com/avago-technologies/hdsp-h103/display-seven-segment-14-2mm-red/dp/1003299 20mA instead of 5mA. So, which one is correct?

Comment: And my apologies for buying up all of the $5 and $10 copies of the HP manual. I've got a nice shelf of them that I'm hoarding. (Waiting for the LED apocalypse.) ;)

Comment: Is there no display that actually have the same layout. For example with 2-4 line LCD's mostly still follow the old school Hitachi layout and protocol.

Comment: High efficiency red LEDs are the area you want to find. You might call OSRAM and see if they can direct you. I contracted with them regarding a wide range of LED modules they needed binned and analyzed. Good folks. Or were, anyway.

Comment: I'm not aware of any. Certainly, you may find some that I wouldn't easily find. I'm not going to spend a lot of time on it. But I think you could. Try calling the serious folks in this business area. Like OSRAM.

Comment: If you do decide to try using individual digit displays, be wary. Unless they are carefully binned for you the digits likely won't match each other well. Though red is easier due to the poor human ability to discern differences in the redder regions. But brightness perception is still an issue.

Comment: Are you sure the problem isn't with the Automatic-Brightness-Control? (see the CDS photocell next to the LED module)

Comment: @ami: The problem isn't the ABC-LDR, it is a little brighter when shorted, same brightness as the dots. The dots are not affected by light intensity.

Comment: @ami: See my answer. Disabled the ABC, it is now better at night.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can buy individual **common-cathode** displays and use discrete LEDs for the four additional LED colon and anunciator positions. There will be a bit of wiring to do, which could be done with a bit of perf board and some solder-through magnet wire of ~AWG30. Should not take very long.

You'll have to evaluate if there is enough room, you'll need something like 11 or 12 mm thickness, which is probably more than the original display.

For example, Rohm [LA-601EL](https://www.rohm.com/datasheet/LA-601EB/la-601bl-e). Use indicator LEDs with similar nm wavelength to the LED displays to reasonably match the colors. You might need to fiddle with the discrete leds by adding tubes, flattening the ends or doing something like that to get a good appearance, but fortunately they're cheap so experimentation is no problem.

A modern LED display such as the Rohm will be much brighter than the old displays at the same current, possible way too bright. Since you have a way to dim it, that should not be a problem.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the great answer. Nice idea however the 'glass' of the case is transparent (it isn't a dark window) so any change made is visible. There is a dark red diffuser on top of the original display that cannot be taken off without damage because it is heavily glued (cannot reused). Have done this before with a sony clock display with same problem and destroyed the film/diffuser (by carefully peeling off). When it is possible to find a diffuser, your solution could be an awesome solution because there is enough space left to implement this.

Comment: Just for info: The sony display I am talking about have a black frame with segments cutouts instead of a white frame. To make the display brighter, I removed the green diffusor and replaced with a transparent diffuser (of backlight) of an old LCD screen. This was possible because the frame was a black one, result isn't that bad/ugly. Replacing the colored diffuser with a transparent one makes the display less dim, not a real solution. Because your solution is much brighter, I have to find such material to 'hide' the implementation behind a colored transparent window. Any ideas?

Comment: Build it up with a 3-d printed or X-acto knife cut (from black-painted foamcore) frame and add a thin red filter in front.

Comment: @Sphero: Great idea, black foam. But what is the material of the thin red filter? Can I buy this somewhere? Searched on the web and cannot find anything.

Comment: Look for filters “gels” used in stage and similar lighting. You can even find assortments on Amazon but theatrical supply outfits carry a wide range. There are sources of other materials that are more suitable for mass production situations, but as you just want one...

Comment: PS. Foamcore (generically foam board) is a sandwich of smooth white cardboard and foam. You can find it in any graphic arts supply shop, and probably in most fine arts shops. There is even an all - black version available. You still might want to paint the outward facing side to get it flat black rather than glossy.

Answer (score 0):

Inspect what controls the Intensity input on pin 5 of the MK IC and record the range of voltages.

This should control the common cathode voltage on pins 1 or 24 of the LED display, where, closer to 0V is a brighter display .  Each segment is rated for 15mA absolute max, 10mA typical  but is probably operating at <100uA from the brightness indicated.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. When I connect the ground pin (pin 1) of the display directly to ground, it is at full brightness, the same as the dots (dots are not affected by light intensity)  however isn't very bright.

Comment: What about V pin 5? And is Vcc=5V?

Comment: Vdd = 5.8v which is plausible because datasheet specify 6v. Take a look at my answer, I disabled the ABC-feature.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a real solution however it is some better now by shorting the pins of the ABC-LDR (Auto Brightness Control) at the front. Especially at night (dark room) it is an improvement. Don't want to spend more time on it and don't want to ruin something, leave it this way for now. At daylight it is still not very bright. I made it easily reversible, when I find better solution it is easy to reverse this fix.

[image: display fix]

Comment: Increasing Vdd will increase current slightly. Measuring Vf on Segment may reveal current. If >2V